# Libre Base create field on date and auto increment value

Tags: sql, libreoffice, radix

I have inherited an excel spreadsheet of ~7000 jobs that I want to turn into a database. I am trying to write a new job entry form. One of the fields is a job ID that is the (YY) year followed by a three digit sequential number, eg 16001,16002... Clearly this will need to change with the year and for this reason using this as the primary key is unsuitable. It is highly unlikely there will be more than 999 jobs per year.

Could anybody explain how I can get the field in the form and subsequent table entry to update automatically with the next job ID? I can access the last entry value with Tools>SQL>SELECT... statement and even return that value + 1 but cannot figure out how to create a field in my form that can automatically display this value.

Thanks all

Axel

Answer (score 0):

There are good examples (credit: user [DACM](https://forum.openoffice.org/en/forum/memberlist.php?mode=viewprofile&u=26423)) on using database forms in the OpenOffice community forum, see: **[[Example] Invoice Forms (without macros)](https://forum.openoffice.org/en/forum/viewtopic.php?f=100&t=56006)**

Have fun!